# Is there already a tool which can fossilize (turn into static HTML) a Mattermost?

Tags: json

So we have a couple Mattermost servers for different departments of the organization. One department is closing down, and we don't want to keep maintaining their Mattermost forever, but we do want the data to still be accessible.

I found that you can export Mattermost data into a ZIP file which contains all the files linked along with a JSON lines file with the text posted in the channels.

Now I could write a program to turn the content of that ZIP into a static HTML website, but I was wondering if someone had already done this job before. Is there already a Mattermost plugin which can turn a channel into static HTML, or failing that, a readable document?

Or is there a tool which can, with minimal configuration, turn a JSON lines file into an HTML or other readable document?